# Rails set cronjob for different time interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

hello I am fetching time of different countries as i have done in my code now i want to set a cron job in such way that for A particluar interval a service should get start eg when in INDIA the time is 5:00 the service will start and same goes on with usa and china also when in newyork it will be 5 the service will get start and same goes with china ..I don't know how to use that time . I am able to fetch time of respective countries but unable call the service for the particular interval

```
s = Rufus::Scheduler.new
s.every '1m' do 
    usa = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
    india=TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Kolkata')
    china=TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Shanghai')

    k = india.now.to_s
    puts k.split(' ')[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly. You want to be able to detect the current time on different countries, and if for some "times" in some countries, you want to trigger different events? If so, here is how you can do it:

```
s = Rufus::Scheduler.new
s.every '1m' do 
  usa = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
  india=TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Kolkata')
  china=TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Shanghai')

  k = india.now
  puts k.split(' ')[1]

  if k.hour == 5 && k.min == 0
    # do action for india at 5:00
  elsif # another case etc

  end
end
```